# Noun + Past Participle = Present Perfect?

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

From *The Blister Exists* by Slipknot:
chorus:

> I am the damaged one
>   All my life and the damage done

The question: why the damage done? As I understand, sometimes past participle can give some qualities of adjective to a noun or object. For example:
I saw a broken door yesterday. We can ask: "What door"? "What exactly is the door?" or "What door did you see yesterday?... a broken door..
And, could you explain the sense of "the damage done" and is it possible to say "the work done" or smth else

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to say **the damage done** or **the work done** or **the question asked** or **the answer given** or **the road taken** or **the shot fired**. or **the money spent** or **the pain inflicted** or **the love withheld** or **the solace offered** or **the word misspelled**. **the money lost** and **the money gained**, **the hopes abandoned** and **the lions tamed**.

I think some analyses of the past participle when it follows the noun  would treat it as a clause-in-miniature rather than as adjectival modifier.

the damage [which is] done.

the question [which was] asked.

With absolute omission of a relative and BE, rather than ellipsis.